# Windows keeps giving me this Error 0x80004005: Unspecified Error during deleting a folder

Tags: windows, bash, cmd, directory, delete-file

I've just downloaded a folder from my drive and extracted the files to the current directory. But I couldn't open the folder, File Explorer said the files in the folder don't exist. Then I tried to delete the folder and it failed with Unspecified Error. I've tried another methods to delete the folder, like...

```
del /f folder_name
```

On my GNU Bash, I've tried...

```
rm -fr folder_name
```

So any of them didn't work. Is there any way to delete this folder?

Here's the picture.

[image: trailing dot in folder name]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a trailing dot in  `"Something about school."` folder name. Run the following command (could require elevated privileges / open command prompt as administrator, see also my answer to [similar question at SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/997621/376602)):

```
del "\\?\C:\Users\mete\…-24\Something about school."
```

Note that `…` ([horizontal ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis)) placeholder above indicates omitted part of path.

[About the `\\?\` prefix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#namespaces):

> For file I/O, the "`\\?\`" prefix to a path string tells the Windows
>   APIs to disable all string parsing and to send the string that follows
>   it straight to the file system.
>
> ...
>
> Because it turns off automatic expansion of the path string, the
>   "`\\?\`" prefix also allows the use of "`..`" and "`.`" in the path
>   names, which can be useful if you are attempting to perform operations
>   on a file with these otherwise reserved relative path specifiers as
>   part of the fully qualified path.

Note that you cannot use the "`\\?\`" prefix with a relative path.

Comment: Firstly really thanks about this. And there is a one thing that makes me confusing hard. Is there a big difference or even a difference between Linux and Windows I/O rules?

Comment: Worked like a charm... in my case for a directory, using:
rmdir "\\?\C:\Users\some_folder_named_with_dot_at_end." /S